# Knockoutjs Options Binding with JSON data?

Tags: json, knockout.js

I am trying to list the options for a `select` tag from server with the help of knockout options binding. I have a PHP page which returns the JSON data which is pushed to a knockout observable array which is binded to the select tag. But somehow it is not working, please refer to the following code for reference:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option data-bind="options: Country_Names, optionsText: 'country_name'"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function appModel(session_info){
        /* Session Info related bindings are commented as they are working fine */
        var self = this;
        this.Country_Names = ko.observableArray();

        // Bindings related to the batch processing
        $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"../api/master_list.php",
                type:"get",
                data:{mastertype: '1'},
                cache:false,
                success:function(country_list){
                    ko.mapping.fromJSON(country_list, {}, self.Country_Names);
                }
            });
        });
    };

    $.ajax({
        url:"../api/sessions.php",
        type:"get",
        data: {rqtype: '1'},
        cache:false,
        success:function(session_info){
            var data = $.parseJSON(session_info);
            if (data.status == 'Invalid_id'){
                window.location.replace('../files/main.html');
            } else {
                ko.applyBindings(new appModel(session_info));
            }
        }
    });    
});
```

Sample JSON:

```
[{"country_name":"Albania"},{"country_name":"Chile"},{"country_name":"Cuba"}]
```

Question, Why are the options not listed in the select tag? Am i missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are data-binding the `option` element, whereas you want to put the bindings on the `select`, like this:

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: Country_Names, optionsText: 'country_name'">
</select>
```

The `<option...>` element is gone; the options will be generated by Knockout.

Note that [the relevant documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) is very clear on how all this works. If you haven't already, I suggest (re-)reading it.

Or, see this full demo:

```js
var data = [{"country_name":"Albania"},{"country_name":"Chile"},{"country_name":"Cuba"}];

ko.applyBindings({ Country_Names: data });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: Country_Names, optionsText: 'country_name'"></select>
```

Comment: @Max Good point. That was why the essential code was already also in the question. To be complete, I've reconstructed the fiddle from memory (or rather: by instinct) and added it as a runnable snippet to the answer. PS. The runnable code *is* or IMHO at least *should* be considered superfuous, as the documentation is very clear about how all this works.